# Only using 20% of CPU after multiprocessing.pool.starmap() in python

Tags: performance, python-multiprocessing, cpu-usage, python-3.7

The intention of the program is to run through a directory, if a file is an excel spreadsheet it should open it, extract and manipulate some data then move onto the next file. As this is a laborious process I have tried to split the task across multiple threads. Even after this is only using 20% of the total CPU capacity, and it didn't particular speed up.

```
def extract_data(unique_file_names):
    global rootdir
    global newarray
    global counter
    global t0
    string = rootdir + "\\" + str(unique_file_names[0])
    wb = load_workbook(string, read_only = True,  data_only=True)
    ws = wb["Sheet1"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
    newarray = df.loc[4:43,:13].values

    counter = 0
    print("Starting pool")
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=20)
    pool.map(process, unique_file_names)    
    pool.close() 

def process(filename):
    global newarray
    global unique_file_names
    global counter
    global t0
    counter+=1

    try: 
        file_name = rootdir + "/" + str(filename)
        wb = load_workbook(file_name, read_only = True,  data_only=True)
        ws = wb["Sheet1"]
        df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
        newarray = np.hstack((newarray, df.loc[4:43,4:13].values))
    except:
        print("Failure")
        pass

    print("Time   %.2f,  Completed  %.2f %% " %((time.clock()-t0),counter*100/len(unique_file_names)))
```

So it roughly takes around a second and a half to process one spreadsheet, but like I said pool.map() made next to no difference. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Be aware of the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) inside Python

Comment: I was under the impression that using multiprocessing rather than threading was the solution to GIL?

Comment: In principle it should be. But there are corner-cases and side effects, and cost of [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). BTW, did you try the same on Linux?

Comment: I haven't got the ability to do this on linux. Just checked now, im using 15/16 GB but yet barely any CPU. 

Im not sure if this is me incorrectly using pools but for the function i use in pool.starmap(myfunc, [a,b]) in myfunc() i have a print statement, which I'd assume would reoccur, but it hasn't printed once! - Edit: It seems using so much RAM has crashed the program!

Comment: What do you see in `top`?  Most of the work here is probably just in IO (i.e. reading the files) therefore the multiple cores aren't being utilized.  Also, how many cores do you have?

Comment: In top? Not sure I understand. I have 8 cores